# R get list of packages that have a more recent CRAN version

Tags: r

How can I get a dataframe of all the packages that have a more recent version in CRAN?  For example:

```
df <- check_outdated_packages() # please create this function

>df
     package    installed_version    latest_cran_version
      <char>               <char>                 <char>
1: reactable                0.3.0                  0.4.4
```

Comment: Look at functions `available.packages()` and `installed.packages()`. Or just listen to @BenBolker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?old.packages` says:

> ‘old.packages’ indicates packages which have a (suitable) later
> version on the repositories whereas ‘update.packages’ offers to
> download and install such packages.

it returns:

> ‘NULL’ or a matrix with one row per package,
> row names the package names and column names ‘"Package"’,
> ‘"LibPath"’, ‘"Installed"’ (the version), ‘"Built"’ (the version
> built under), ‘"ReposVer"’ and ‘"Repository"’.

On my system right now:

```
        Package    LibPath                         Installed Built   ReposVer
admisc   "admisc"   "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "0.31"    "4.3.0" "0.32"  
clock    "clock"    "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "0.6.1"   "4.3.0" "0.7.0" 
markdown "markdown" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "1.6"     "4.4.0" "1.7"   
rticles  "rticles"  "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "0.24"    "4.3.0" "0.25"  
MASS     "MASS"     "/usr/local/lib/R/library"      "7.3-59"  "4.4.0" "7.3-60"

         Repository                               
admisc   "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
clock    "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
markdown "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
rticles  "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
MASS     "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
```

(I thought I remembered this existed: I did `apropos("package")` to find it.)